# Web Programming: Includes Facebook as an iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

Having trouble: I cannot link to facebook.com by another url or by an iframe, because they mabye blocked that... How can I include FB to my site (it is to handle a block of a server service (which blocks FB, youtube and other stuff))...

How can I include it anyway, without facebook recognizing that i'm just including as an iframe?

Thx for help, flo

Comment: Are you taking about facebook connect?

Comment: Not really, I'm just trying to show an iframe with source facebook.com, but this seems not to work.... because facebook has blocked this somehow, i think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook checks to see if it is in a frame or iframe and refuses to load if it is. If you want to overcome that or if you are trying to bypass an internet filter (sounds like you are in high school or something) you would have to use a proxy of some sort, and facebook is incompatible with almost all proxies.

If you are desperate I have successfully tunneled facebook through secure shell on a linux server, it's a bit complicated but works.

Comment: Oh this sounds nice... I'll write you a mail ;)